# ¿Cómo relacionar datos por índice en multiples arrays (o archivos csv)?

Tags: python, lista, csv

Estoy cargando tres archivos.csv. Convertí estos archivos en tres listas para hacerlos más fáciles de manipular y obtener ciertos datos para calcular y realizar operaciones. El problema es que necesito correlacionar estos tres archivos.csv o listas para obtener los datos apropiados:

**Quiero calcular el número de personas (hombres o mujeres) por rango de edad que calificaron películas de cierto género.**

**Nombre de archivos:**

- **movies.csv** : contiene (separados por comas) un identificador de la película, el título de la película y sus géneros separados por el caracter |.

  > Movie_ID, Movie_Title, Gender1 | Gender2 | ...
  >
  > > 1,Toy Story (1995),Animation|Children’s|Comedy
- **rate.csv** : contiene una nota que un usuario hizo en una
  película particular. En este caso, sólo se utilizan comas para separar los campos.

  > User_ID, Movie_ID, Rating
  >
  > > 1,1193,5
- **users.csv** : contiene (separado por comas) un identificador de
  usuario, género ("M": masculino, "F": femenino) y rango de edad (1: menor de 18, 18: entre 18-24, 25: entre 25-34, 35: entre 35-44, 45: entre 45-49, 50: entre 50-55, 56: mayor que 55).

  > User_ID, Gender, Age_Range
  >
  > > 1,F,1

**Mi código:**

```py
def opFiles_to_list(filename):
  '''abre un csv y lo convierte en lista'''
  with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",", lineterminator = '\n')
    new_list = list(reader)
  return new_list

def extract_list(lista, pos, dato):
  '''extrae datos específicos en cierto índice de una lista'''
  l = []
  index = 0
  for i in lista:
    index += 1
    if i[pos] == str(dato):
      l.append(lista[index - 1]) 
  return l


def estadisticos(genero_persona, genero_pelicula):
  rango = 0
  '''calcula la cantidad de personas por rango etario según la calificación de películas por determinado género'''
  notas_list = opFiles_to_list(notas)
  users_list = opFiles_to_list(usuarios)
  pelis_list = opFiles_to_list(peliculas)

  users_ext = extract_list(users_list, 1, genero_persona) # pos género persona
  pelis_ext = extract_list(pelis_list, 2, genero_pelicula)  # pos género película

  for f in pelis_ext:
    print(f)
  for s in users_ext:
    print(s)

  return rango
```

**output esperado:**

- Calcular el número de personas (hombres o mujeres) por rango de edad que calificaron películas de cierto género: entiéndase que para esto es necesario correlacionar los tres archivos csv o las tres listas (lo que se considere más fácil de manipular).

```py
Ingresar género: M
Ingresar género pelicula: Comedy
Menor Rank 18: 2184
Rank 18-24: 11239
Rank 25-34: 22597
Rank 35-44: 11489
Rank 45-49: 5548
Rank 50-55: 4184
Mayor rank 56: 2066
```

**output actual:**
Si imprimo la `pelis_ext` **solamente** obtendré películas delimitadas por `,` y, por ejemplo, del género Comedia, sin incluir las que están delimitadas por `|`, por ejemplo Comedia|Drama|Animación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver el problema de los géneros basta con usar `str.split` y separar por `"|"`.

Por otro lado, dado que se asume que las ids de película y usuario son únicas y además se usan en `rate` para enlazar con los otros dos csv, usar un diccionario con la id como clave para almacenar los datos de `movies.csv` y `users.csv` es una buena idea para facilitar las búsquedas.

Obtendríamos algo así:

> ```
> >>> movies_dict
>
> {'1': {'title': 'Toy Story (1995)',
>        'gender': {'Animation', 'Children’s', 'Comedy'}
>       },
>  '2': {....
>       },
>   ....
> }
>
> >>> users_dict
> {'1': {'age_range': '1',
>        'gender': 'F'
>       }
>  '2': {'age_range': '25',
>        'gender': 'M'
>       },
>  ...
> }
> ```

Con esto, buscar el usuario y la película identificados mediante sus ids en rate es trivial y eficiente.

Podrías hacer por tanto algo así:

```
import csv


movies = {}
with open("movies.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for id_, title, gender  in reader:
        movies[id_] = {"title": title, "gender": set(gender.split("|"))}

users = {}
with open("users.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for id_, gender, age_range  in reader:
        users[id_] = {"age_range": age_range, "gender": gender}


genero = input("Ingresar género: ")
genero_pelicula = input("Ingresar género pelicula: ")    
count = {"1": 0, "18": 0, "25": 0, "35": 0, "45": 0, "50": 0, "56": 0}

with open("rate.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for user_id, movie_id, _  in reader:
        user = users.get(user_id)
        movie = movies.get(movie_id)
        if user["gender"] == genero and genero_pelicula in movie["gender"]:
            count[user["age_range"]] += 1

print(f"Menor Rank 18: {count['1']}",
      f"Rank 18-24: {count['18']}",
      f"Rank 25-34: {count['25']}",
      f"Rank 35-44: {count['35']}",
      f"Rank 45-49: {count['45']}",
      f"Rank 50-55: {count['50']}",
      f"Mayor rank 56: {count['56']}",
      sep="\n"
      )
```

Se asume que toda id presente en rate.csv está presente en los otros dos diccionarios, aunque de no ser así bastaría con comprobar que los métodos `dict.get` no retornen `None`.